# Jquery toggleClass on icon without affecting the other icons with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several `divs` with the same svg as bg-img (basically audio player buttons) and I would like to toggle the class of every clicked element without affecting the others. I don't really know how to properly select the very single emelemnt I am clicking on and not all of them at the same time.

The html is:

```
<ol class="tracks">
  <li>some text
    <div class="play"></div>
  </li>
  <li>some text 
    <div class="play"></div>
  </li>
  ...
</ol>
```

I place the same svg in each div as bg-img.

Of course I cannot toggle the `.play` as I would just change all the `divs` at the same time, so I tried `$this`:

```
$('.play').click(function() {
  $this.toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

On the `clicked` class I would simply change the bg-img (say, from play.svg to pause.svg and vice versa).
Evidently there is something wrong with my Jquery but, being still a noob, I cannot figure out what it would be.

I would really appreciate if you could help me. ^_^

Comment: `$(this).toggleClass('clicked');`

Comment: Oh my! Stupid brackets. Stupid me! ahhah! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is correct. It will work. Update your js to:

```
$('.play').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```

See example changing class here: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/zLx03L1u/1/

Comment: Thank you! j08691 also gave me this answer and it's working! :)